# How to UnMount a Component in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a wizard that has many forms, at the end of the wizard I want to take them back to the first step. However every form is filled in with the previous values.

I just want to unmount and remount it to wipe everything clean. How do I do this in reactjs?

```
 <StepWizard>
          <Step>
           <NewComponent/>
          </Step>
          <Step>
          <NewComponent/>
          </Step>
          <Step>
            <NewComponent/>
          </Step>
          <Step>
            <NewComponent/>
          </Step>
        </StepWizard>
```

so how would I trigger something to just get "StepWizard" to render in a fresh state?

My components look something like this, I removed code that switches to the next step in the wizard.

```
export default class NewComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          name: "",
          website: "",
        }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
          name: Yup.string().required('Company Name is Required'),
          website: Yup.string().url('Company Url is Invalid'),
        })}
        onSubmit={(
          values,
          { setSubmitting, setErrors}
        ) => {
        }}
        render={({
          values,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          setFieldValue,
          setFieldTouched
        }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="field">
              <label className="label">Name</label>
              <div className="control">
                <input
                  className="input"
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  maxLength="50"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  value={values.name}
                />
                   <ErrorMessage name="name"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label className="label">Website</label>
              <div className="control">
                 <Field  className="input" name="website"  type="text" />
                 <ErrorMessage name="website"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I am using Mbox State Tree, so I could store something in my store that could be used to trigger whatever needs to be triggered to cause a reset.

Edit

I should mention that I am using this plugin: https://github.com/jcmcneal/react-step-wizard

So I am not sure if stopping a step from rendering is an option, also then that would mean I would have to handle the previous step state everytime.

I am more looking for something that just blows away everything if possible as I spent already too much time on this area and don't want to rework tons.

Comment: Please post sample code snippets of your component(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlighting the above methods you can also do something like this. Lift the default state into an object that can be pre-filled by whatever, hydrate it into the state and then when you call a reset you can control how much you reset the state back to. This is a very generic example but it's one way to overcome your issue.

[Click here to view a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/52j1jzwx8l)

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// generic stage renderer
const Stage = ({ step, currentStep, children }) => {
  return step === currentStep ? <div>{children}</div> : null;
};

// generic input controller
const Input = ({ stateKey, value, handleOnChange }) => (
  <input
    value={value}
    onChange={evt => handleOnChange(stateKey, evt.target.value)}
  />
);

// default state that is used to reference
const defaultState = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  // default state can also be prefilled with data..
  telephoneNumber: '0123456789',
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    step: 1,
    ...defaultState
  };
  handleStateUpdate = (key, value) => {
    this.setState({
      [key]: value
    });
  };
  incrementStep = () => {
    if (this.state.step < 3) {
      this.setState({
        step: this.state.step + 1
      });
    }
  };
  goBack = () => {
    const { step, lastName, telephoneNumber } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: 1,
      // always reset this one
      firstName: defaultState.firstName,
      // only reset this one if it's step 3
      lastName: step > 2
        ? defaultState.lastName
        : lastName,
      // last step blargh, let's reset anyway
      telephoneNumber: step === 3
        ? defaultState.telephoneNumber 
        : telephoneNumber,
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { step, firstName, lastName, telephoneNumber } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
        <h1>Step Wizard - {step}</h1>
        <Stage step={1} currentStep={step}>
          <Input
            stateKey="firstName"
            value={firstName}
            handleOnChange={this.handleStateUpdate}
          />
        </Stage>
        <Stage step={2} currentStep={step}>
          <Input
            stateKey="lastName"
            value={lastName}
            handleOnChange={this.handleStateUpdate}
          />
        </Stage>
        <Stage step={3} currentStep={step}>
          <Input
            stateKey="telephoneNumber"
            value={telephoneNumber}
            handleOnChange={this.handleStateUpdate}
          />
        </Stage>
        <button onClick={this.goBack}>Go Back to Step 1</button>
        <button onClick={this.incrementStep}>Next</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by storing the current state of the wizard in, you guessed it, state object. That state and actions to mutate it can be passed to children as props. After that, when you need to reset the wizard, you just reset the state.

Here's an oversimplified example:

```
class StepWizard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      step1: {},
      step2: {}
    };
  }

  setStep(step, data) {
    this.setState({ `step${ step }`: data });
  }

  resetWizard() {
    this.setState({
      step1: {},
      step2: {}
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Step
          data={ this.state.step1 }
          setData={ (data)=> this.setStep(1, data) }
          />
        <Step
          data={ this.state.step2 }
          setData={ (data)=> this.setStep(2, data) }
          />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, call `resetWizard` whenever you'll need to reset the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a Step object that would have the render logic for each step? I understand your use case correctly, since you would want to render only one step at a time why not only render which is relevant at that particular step?

Something like below.

```
class Wizard {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.stepMap = {
        first: <FirstStep />,
        second: <SecondtStep />,
        third: <ThirdStep />,
        fourth: <FourthStep />
    }

    this.state = {
        activeStep: "first"
    }
  }

  changeStep = (stepId) => {
    this.setState({activeStep: stepId});
  }

  render() {
    const activeStepCmp = this.stepMap[this.state.activeStep];

    return (
      <StepWizard>
        {activeStepCmp}
      </StepWizard>
    )
  }
}
```